# How can payment with another account of same device in IN APP PURCHASE android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Actually in my device there are two gmail accounts logged in(firstaccount@gmail.com , secondaccount@gmail.com). Now when I logged in into app and press the button for payment IN APP PURCHASE popup will appear(which shown in image) for firstaccount@gmail.com and completed the payment procedure, after that I logged out from my installed app and try to relogin with another account and at a time I want to pay from my device secondaccount@gmail.com but I can not. And errors occurs (Error code :7) product is already purchase. so how can I change account for payment in app time.

[image: In both case i am getting same email for payment]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

1) Uninstall the application first.
2) Open the app in play store in WEB BROWSER in your computer.
3) Make sure you are logged in using the correct account.
4) Select install and then select correct phone.
5) Once installation is completed in phone, it should show the correct account.

Comment: Do you think that all users will do this stuff ??

Comment: This is THE SOLUTION! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is Developer Payload option in purchase and subscription method.

This Developer Option is used for to save your information about purchase where you can keep your unique details about purchase. (Like Purchased Registered Email ID for Your Application)

Thus whenever another user login in your application you can fetch purchase details with developer payload. Thus fetched developer payload details match with login user if same then it is same user login who has been purchased otherwise it's different user.

There is one disadvantage another user login can not purchase same item if one has purchased using same account.

This method is useful when one has purchased that used should consume purchase that item but if any other user can also login in that device but he should not used that item if not purchased for same.

This can be managed by API side too.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to reproduce:
1. Uninstall the app that you made the purchase with.
2. Add a second Google account to the device.
3. Open Google Play and switch to the new Google account.
4. Download the app you uninstalled in step 1.
5. Open the app and query for purchases. The previous purchase is not reported.

Fix A (only works if the account used to make the purchase is the "primary" account on the device):
1. Clear the data of the Google Play Store app.
2. Open the Google Play Store and accept the terms.
3. Open the app and query for purchases. The previous purchase is reported.

Fix B:
1. Uninstall the app.
2. Open Google Play and switch to the account used to make the purchase.
3. Download the app you uninstalled in step 1.
4. Open the app and query for purchases. The previous purchase is reported.

Comment: Ok i got it. you are right at your point of view but users will suffer from this long process. so I am finding any other way to solve this issue ?

Comment: yeah i got your problem this issue is been reported 3 years ago still if you get any workaround please add your answer